# Overwritting the Element.prototype.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am going to find all the elements to which a function has been attached through `addEventListener` on the DOM. So, I tried to overwrite the `Element.prototype.addEventListener` method. 
I trided to test the script on [this website](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/27/beautiful-photo-stack-gallery-with-jquery-and-css3/) which is available.
The first interesting part is that if I put my script inside the `head` tag of the HTML. The website won't be rendered. Also, if I put it on top of its existing Scripts the website won't be rendered either. My Script needs to be located after the Script which is supposed to load the `JQuery` library. Then, it works.

My problem is that, the Script works fine and it gives me the XPath of all the elements to which a function should be attached but, when the webpage loads there is no function attached to those elements anymore. Also, if I click on each elements, the new DOM won't be rendered since the `addEventListener` method is called again and it seems that my Script does not work anymore.

I fail to find what is the problem with my function which prevents the website to work fine.

```
<script>

var arrayOfElms = new Array();
var OriginalAddEventListener = Element.prototype.addEventListener;

var EventListener = function(type,listener) {
    console.log('add event listener was called');
    OriginalAddEventListener(type, listener);
    arrayOfElms.push(getXPath(this));
};

Element.prototype.addEventListener = EventListener;


function getXPath(elm) { 
    var allNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*'); 
    for (var segs = []; elm && elm.nodeType == 1; elm = elm.parentNode) 
    { 
        if (elm.hasAttribute('id')) { 
                var uniqueIdCount = 0; 
                for (var n=0;n < allNodes.length;n++) { 
                    if (allNodes[n].hasAttribute('id') && allNodes[n].id == elm.id) uniqueIdCount++; 
                    if (uniqueIdCount > 1) break; 
                }; 
                if ( uniqueIdCount == 1) { 
                    segs.unshift('id("' + elm.getAttribute('id') + '")'); 
                    return segs.join('/'); 
                } else { 
                    segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[@id="' + elm.getAttribute('id') + '"]'); 
                } 
        } else if (elm.hasAttribute('class')) { 
            segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[@class="' + elm.getAttribute('class') + '"]'); 
        } else { 
            for (i = 1, sib = elm.previousSibling; sib; sib = sib.previousSibling) { 
                if (sib.localName == elm.localName)  i++; }; 
                segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[' + i + ']'); 
        }; 
    }; 
    return segs.length ? '/' + segs.join('/') : null; 
}

</script>
```

Comment: This line: `OriginalAddEventListener(type, listener);` isn't going to work, because you aren't telling the function which element to bind the listener to.

Comment: How can I tell that to the function?

Comment: `OriginalAddEventListener.call(this, type, listener);` - for more info see [MDN's `call()` doco](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [explanation of `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).